# SQL where not source: 'user' clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to select all Posts with no images from source 'user'. Other sources allowed. How can I achieve it?

```
Post.includes(:images).where.not(images: { source: Image.sources[:user] })
```

> Image belongs_to :post
>
> Post has_many :images
>
> Image.source is 'int'

Comment: is this one not working?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko it returns Posts that have images with any source (==source not nil)

Comment: did you find a solution?